# How can i find out which sort of technology a propriatery wireless device uses to send their signals

Tags: wireless-bridge, signal, bluetooth-3.0

Hello I'm a type 1 diabetic and I've been offered what's called a continous glucose monitor. Now I'm also sort of paranoid about having too many signals in my surrounding, I know the consensus is that modern wireless technology is just hunky dory regarding safety, but I'm not sure that I agree so I keep it to a minimum where everything in my house is cabled except my phone. Disagree with me if you want, but many very intelligent people agree with included former WHO-director Gro Harlem Brundtland.

So for two of the devices I've been offered (Dexcom, Libre) I've found out that they use Bluetooth for their signals simply by googling, but I can't seem to find out what the third device (Medtronic) I've been offered uses to send their signals to the pump. Does some sort of device exist that identifies all wireless signals in a room and sorts them out in different categories so that I maybe could get close to someone with a medtronic and figure out what it does?

Comment: I think this is an XY question.  I believe (after listening to talks from a security minded hacker with a medical condition) The solution should be to work with your doctor (change doctor if he wont help) to get the detailed info you need.

Comment: I'm aware of three technologies that have been used for wireless devices:  radio frequencies (aka RF), infrared, and ultrasonic (probably obsolete today when compared to infrared).  There is no single device that could *"identify all wireless signals in a room and sorts them out in different categories"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying a device's radio communications with a spectrum analyzer or software-defined radio is possible, but difficult. There's a much easier way to do this.

Find the FCC ID for the device. This may be printed on the device; if not, it should be in the manual. The FCC ID for a Medtronic device will probably start with the characters "LF5", usually followed by four or five more digits (often the same as the device's model number).

Once you have this information, you can [search for it on the FCC web site](https://www.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid), or on certain third-party web sites like [fccid.io](https://fccid.io/). The information there will include the radio frequencies which the device uses and the power it transmits on those frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools called **spectrum analyzers** that scan the radio-frequency (RF) spectrum looking for sources of energy and graph out the energy level they saw at each frequency they scanned. So you can use a spectrum analyzer to look for a spike in energy that gets taller when you get closer to the transmitter. However spectrum analyzers are generally not consumer equipment and often cost a lot of money. Especially ones that can deal with modern higher frequencies like the 2.4 and 5GHz bands. But see below about RTL-SDR solutions.

Also, any device with a radio transmitter sold in the US will have an "FCC ID" which you can use on the fcc.gov website to look up the frequency and power details of the transmitter. You might be able to Google the model number and "fcc id" to find it, and then plug the FCC ID into the FCC website to find the details. You could also ask your doctor or technician to look for an FCC ID label on a unit they already have, or in the regulatory compliance section of the user manual or other documentation.

If you look up the FCC information and still want to see the signals for yourself, if the frequency is below 2.2GHz you can buy a cheap US$30 USB dongle known as an "RTL SDR" like an Elonics E4000 that can act as a poor man's spectrum analyzer. These "Software-Defined Radios" (SDRs) can also be used with software that can help you decode the signal modulation and possibly even read the data that is being transmitted (if it's not encrypted or you know the key).

Overall, I'd be much less worried about the health effects of the radio transmissions and more worried about the security and encryption work that they did. You don't want some jerk to be able to send a signal to your insulin pump to make it malfunction.